# My App Keeps Crashing After I Use 'AppCompat.NoActionBar', Any Solution?

Tags: java, xml

After using this code my app is keeps crashing

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

I have also tried this one but problem remains the same

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

and this in manifest for above style, but still not helpful

```
<activity
   android:name=".activities.FullViewActivity"
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" 
/>
```

Actually i'm using VideoActivity as a splash screen, here is my java file for Videoactivity

```
package com.example.aninterface;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.PlaybackParams;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class Videoactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    VideoView videoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_videoactivity);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.first);

        videoView.setVideoURI(video);


        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                if (isFinishing())

                    return;

                startActivity(new Intent(Videoactivity.this, MainActivity.class));

            }
        });
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //works only from api 23
                PlaybackParams myPlayBackParams = new PlaybackParams();
                myPlayBackParams.setSpeed(2f); //here set speed eg. 0.5 for slow 2 for fast mode
                mp.setPlaybackParams(myPlayBackParams);
                videoView.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

when i run the application my log says this, looking for solution

```
2019-03-16 00:47:55.376 17571-17571/com.example.aninterface E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.aninterface, PID: 17571
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aninterface/com.example.aninterface.Videoactivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.aninterface.Videoactivity.onCreate(Videoactivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
```

Comment: You are using NoActionBar theme but trying to hide the ActionBar again ( getSupportActionBar().hide(); ). That's why it is showing NullPointerException.

Comment: i have also tried this one but i cant get rid of this error. -> 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);} <-